# How factory reset process looks in details?

Tags: factory-reset, bootloader, system, factory-image

So I tried to find answer for this question, but it is very hard to find something other than simple instruction of doing factory reset and backuping data.

I'm interested of detailed process of the factory reset.
When I force system to do this, what is going under the shell.
It is some image on hidden partition from bootloader boots "clear" system? Or maybe it's just deleting user configuration files, and every corrupted system file states same as before reset. Or maybe there is the way of checking hash of critical files and repair them from some kind of recovery image?

Comment: [Tag wiki of factory-reset] (https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) and the questions there are a good starting point //IMHO, your question is amply answered

Comment: are you mixing up ROM flashing with factory reset? it does nothing more than erase userdata

Comment: On Android there is a read-only system partition and a user data partition. Factory reset deletes the user data, the system partition is not touched at all.